# How to get the best 10 (top 10) in a query that is also ordered by another field first?

Tags: ms-access, select

For example I would like to get only the top 10 customer by seller. So it will look like this (without the top 10):

```
Select seller, customer, sells from table order by seller asc, sells desc
```

But this will give me all the values. I would only like to have the first 10 customers for each seller.

Is this even possible in ms-access 2003? If yes, please give me a hint,
thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

On the lines of:

```
SELECT seller,
       customer,
       sells
FROM   table a
WHERE  customerid IN (SELECT TOP 10 customerid
                      FROM   table b
                      WHERE  b.sellerid = a.sellerid
                      ORDER  BY sells DESC)
ORDER  BY seller ASC,
          sells DESC
```

Note that MS Access returns matches, so you may get more than 10 returns. If an exact 10 is required, you can order by a unique ID as well as sells.

Comment: I will test and provide some feedback. It looks nice, but in my context the query is a lot complex. I will try to implement it but it will take time, If you come with a simpler solution, please say ;)

Comment: There is no simpler solution for getting top *n* per group.